# What are the available client libraries for the Mobli API?

Tags: api, mobli

It seems like Mobli has an API now(Beta)..
Are there any known libraries for that?

http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/23/nyc-disrupt-hackathon-details/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will be officially launching our API within the next few days, alongside SDKs for iOS, Android, and php.

Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 0):

In a few days these libraries will be released:
- iOS 
- Android
- PHP